# Modify this line to give alternate format date?

Tags: posts, date

Can this line:

```
$message = str_replace( '[post_date]', $post->post_date, $message );
```

be modified so the date displayed for the [post_date] shortcode is formatted as Saturday, 12/03/16, 08:43 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$post->post_date`, use `get_the_time( $format, $post )`.

The correct PHP date format string for your question is `'d/m/y H:i'`.

... Assuming you want a two digit minute (even when less that 10 minutes). Also, I may have the month and day the wrong way around for you.

The format argument in `get_the_time()` is PHP's native date format - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Then, change your line of code to:

```
$message = str_replace( '[post_date]', get_the_time( 'd/m/y H:i', $post ), $message );
```

Though, I think it'll be easier and neater to just add the `get_the_time( 'd/m/y H:i', $post )` to your template, rather than having to put a shortcode into each post.